# Transform a Gumby newletter form to work with MailChimp

Tags: html, css, mailchimp, newsletter, gumby-framework

I have this form preset from Gumby framework:

```
<ul>
   <li class="append field">
      <input class="wide email input" type="email" />
      <div class="medium primary btn">
         <a href="#">Go</a>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWqLvo)

I'd like to modify it so it would work as a mailchimp newsletter form:

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->

<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/slim-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
   #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
   /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
   We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
   <form action="//mydomain.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=xxxxx&amp;id=xxxxxx" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
      <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
         <label for="mce-EMAIL">Subscribe to our mailing list</label>
         <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
         <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
         <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="hash_number" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
         <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVPMzx)

Could you guide me through the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started with the MailChimp Signup Form you gave and them I merged with the HTML/CSS code you wanted. Here's the code:

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
  <form action="//mydomain.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=xxxxx&amp;id=xxxxxx" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
      <ul>
        <li class="append field">    
          <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="wide email input" id="mce-EMAIL" required>
          <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
          <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="hash_number" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
          <div class="clear medium primary btn">
            <input style="font-weight:bold;" type="submit" value="Go" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>      
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

JSFIDDLE Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/9f3db7Lw/1/

I tried with a 'domain.list-managed' i had to verify it if worked and it was ok. I think you can use it straight out the box if you replace with your domain.

Cheers,
Joel